# Unable to start rails server + rails 4 + ruby-2.0.0-p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

When I run the rails server

```
$ rails server
```

Then I am getting below error

```
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
from /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16:in `<main>'
```

Could you please help me and let me know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you run the `bundle install`?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some problem in installation.

If you are using rvm gemset then run on your gemset.

> rvm pristine

If you are not using gemset then run

> gem pristine --all